# Django form invalid, Field is required, even through input is given

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I am getting invalid form error: this Field is required

views:

```
class ValueSubmitView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'multichoice.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': symptomsForm})


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form =symptomsForm(request.POST)





        if form.is_valid():
            print('is valid called')
            values = form.cleaned_data.get("symptoms")
            print(values)





            return send_rich_text_response(request, {
                'answer': values,
                })

        else:
            print('form invalid', form.errors)
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form}, content_type='text/html')
```

whereas my form.py is

```
class symptomsForm(forms.Form):

    MEDIA_CHOICES=((1,'Dry Cough'),(2,'Loss or diminished sense of smell'),(3,'Sore Throat'),(4,'Weakness'),(5,'Change in Appetite'),(6,'None of above'),)


    symptoms = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        attrs={
            'class':'some classes '
        }
    ),choices=MEDIA_CHOICES)
```

HTML page is:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="submit_form('{% url "Value-Submit-View" %}','Value-Submit-View')"
      class="book-test-drive border pt-3 pl-3 pr-3 pb-1">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <p class="h5-responsive text-center font-weight-bold text-body">Symptoms</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"> {{ form.symptoms }}</div>
    </div>



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-indigo btn-sm btn-submit">
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

I even tried different form fields like char field but didn't work out, getting the same error, I tried this same code in my previous project which work well but the difference is I used it for form model back then

error:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>symptoms<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: Are you submitting this form using AJAX?

Comment: yes i think this form is submitting using AJAX(sorry I don't design the frontend)

Comment: ok it is submitted using ajax I just checked

Comment: Can you tell me the output of request.POST?

Comment: ok i checked the ajax function and i see the mistake actually i m not sending right class to function, its required two-parameter url and class-name,

Comment: and i am sending wrong class to the ajax

Comment: Should I delete this question since I don't know if the answer to this question is helpful to anyone

Comment: To get the url, you need the app_name from the that apps urls.py file followed by the name of the url. `{% url 'myapp:view-name' %}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: yhea I just delete the app name in question since its confidential